# Por que cai em loop infinito no println?

Tags: java, loop

> Construa um programa que seja capaz de efetuar a média de todos os
> argumentos inteiros ou reais recebidos do teclado e imprimi-los.
>
> Argumentos inválidos devem ser desconsiderados (Imprimir uma mensagem
> para cada valor inválido.), sem provocar a exibição de exceções (Exiba
> uma mensagem para o usuário pedindo a ele que informe novamente o
> valor).
>
> O usuário deve digitar S quando desejar encerrar a entrada de
> dados;

Troquei o `S` pelo `5`, mas deve ser `S`, como faço para conseguir ler um `char` no lugar? Não consegui pegar a lógica.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Media {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int i = 0;
        float valor = 0;
        float media = 0;
        
        Scanner v = new Scanner(System.in);
        valor = v.nextFloat();
        
        while(valor != 5){
            System.out.println("Insira um valor: ");
            media += valor;
            i++;
        }
        
        media = valor/i;
        System.out.println("Média é: "+ media);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Você pode usar [classes wrappers](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/o-pacote-java-lang/#14-6-integer-e-classes-wrappers-box)?

Comment: O *loop* infinito ocorre porque o `valor` nunca muda dentro do laço, então não tem como sair. Isso responde a pergunta título. A pergunta do corpo da pergunta é completamente diferente do título e para resolver isso tem que refazer quase todo código.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como [mencionado pelo Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/153337/por-que-cai-em-loop-infinito-no-printf#comment316555_153337), a variável `valor` nunca muda dentro do *loop*, a condição nunca é satisfeita. Atualize `valor` a cada iteração.

Para obter um `char` da entrada, você pode fazer assim:

```
char caractere = v.next().charAt(0);
```

Como alternativa, você pode usar [`Scanner.html#hasNext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext-java.lang.String-) para correr o *loop* até que seja satisfeita uma condição, que seja digitado a letra `S`:

```
int i = 0;
float soma = 0, valor = 0, media = 0;
// ....

try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) { // Libera o recurso após o uso
   while (!scanner.hasNext("S")) { // Corre o loop enquanto não for digitado "S"
       System.out.println("Insira um valor: ");

       // Mais códigos...
       i++;
   }
}
```

Antes de pegar os valores da entrada, verifique se os dados que você quer obter estão disponíveis com [`Scanner.html#hasNextFloat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextFloat--):

```
if (scanner.hasNextFloat()) { // Verifica se a entrada pode ser lido como um float
    valor = scanner.nextFloat();
    soma += valor;
}
```

Fora do [`try`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), você exibe o resultado como já está fazendo, as outras condições do teu exercício, você pode facilmente resolver. :)

```
media = soma / i;
```

Comment: Se puder da ruma olhada abaixo por gentileza, estou com a seguinte dúvida... (adicionei como resposta)