# Array com capacidade dinâmica e como invalidar outros caracteres na leitura

Tags: java, validação

Fiz o código abaixo porém encontrei 2 problemas:

- O valor do vetor está setado como 100 e deve ser a quantidade de números que o usuário quiser.
- Outro problema que encontrei é que o enunciado especifica que deve haver uma validação caso o usuário insira valores inválidos:

> Argumentos inválidos devem ser desconsiderados (Imprimir uma mensagem para cada valor inválido.), sem provocar a exibição de exceções (Exiba uma mensagem para o usuário pedindo a ele que informe novamente o valor).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

//falta tratar valores inválidos

public class Media {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //esse vetor não pode ter valor fixo, o usuário deve inserir quantos valores quiser, como fazer?
        float valor[] = new float[100], media = 0;
        int j = 0, i;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Insira um valor: ");

        while (!scanner.hasNext("S")) {
            System.out.println("Insira um valor: ");
            valor[j] = scanner.nextFloat();
            j++;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            media += valor[i];
        }
        media = media/i;

        System.out.println("Média: "+ media);
    }
}
```

Comment: Usando vetores, a unica forma é inicia-lo depois de pegar o tamanho digitado pelo usuario, setando este valor, algo como `int entrada = scanner.nextInt();  float valor[] = new float[entrada]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Arrays* têm tamanho fixo. Quando precisa de tamanho desconhecido precisa usar um [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Usei porque é a pergunta e pode ser que vá usar em outro lugar depois, no jeito atual nem *array*, nem `ArrayList` é necessário:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Media {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Float> valores= new ArrayList<Float>();
        float acumulador = 0;
        int contador = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Insira um valor: ");
            float valor = scanner.nextFloat();
            if (false) { //vai colocar a valisação aqui
                System.out.println("Valor inválido digite um válido");
                continue;
            }
            valores.add(valor);
            contador++;
            acumulador += valor;
            System.out.println("Deseja inserir outro valor S/N? ");
            if (!scanner.next().equals("S")) {
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < valores.size(); i++) System.out.println("Nota " + (i + 1) + ": " + valores.get(i));
        System.out.println("Média: "+ acumulador / contador);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/nx9Zeq). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/habrxnei-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/Inserting.java).

Mais simples e começando fazer a validação:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Media {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float acumulador = 0;
        int contador = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Insira um valor: ");
            float valor = scanner.nextFloat();
            if (false) { //vai colocar a valisação aqui
                System.out.println("Valor inválido digite um válido");
                continue;
            }
            contador++;
            acumulador += valor;
            System.out.println("Deseja inserir outro valor S/N? ");
            if (!scanner.next().equals("S")) break;
        }
        System.out.println("Média: "+ acumulador / contador);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Q5wjzu). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pywxphmm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/Inserting2.java).

Não coloquei a validação porque a pergunta não descreve como deve ser validado, mas a lógica básica está presente, basta mudar a condição.

Não sei se atende o requisito mas eu faria diferente:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Media {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float acumulador = 0;
        int contador = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Insira um valor: ");
            String dado = scanner.nextLine();
            if (dado.equals("N")) break;
            try {
                float valor = Float.parseFloat(dado);
                contador++;
                acumulador += valor;
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.out.println("Valor inválido digite um válido");
            }
         }
        System.out.println("Média: "+ acumulador / contador);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/03vZrL). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kkqmwvxu-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/Inserting3.java).

Nas próximas perguntas coloque um problema de cada vez e bem definido. Ter feito isso na [pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153337/101) prejudicou as respostas, por isso o que foi postado lá acabou não ajudando solucionar o problema de fato, tanto que aqui não está usando a solução apresentada lá, mesmo tendo aceito uma resposta. Isso aconteceria aqui também.

Eu mudei o código para uma solução adequada. Pelo menos dentro do que eu entendi do problema que não está tão claro. O caminho que estava sendo adotado gerava várias confusões e desperdícios.